# Find the properties of $f(x,y)= \begin{cases} \frac{2(x^3+y^3)}{x^2+2y} & (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\ 0 & (x,y)= (0,0) \end{cases}$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

Suppose, $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by,

$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 
      \frac{2(x^3+y^3)}{x^2+2y} & (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\
      0 &  (x,y)= (0,0)
   \end{cases}$$

then what can we say about the **continuity**, **differentiability** and **partial** **derivatives** of $f$?

My attempt :

> I have computed the partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ at $(0,0)$ by using the formulae,
> $$f_x=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h},\ \ f_y=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h}$$
> I get $f_x=f_y=0.$ I think this shows the continuity and differentiability. But according to the given answer $f$ is not continuous at all.

Can anyone please find out my mistake? And comment about the **continuity**, **differentiability** and **partial** **derivatives** of $f$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $f\left(\sqrt2,-1\right)$?

Comment: Why do you think $f_x = f_y = 0$ shows continuity and differentiability?

Comment: While others have pointed out inconsistency with your answer, I would like to know if the given answer **actually** states "_not continuous at **all**_", because that is incorrect too, over the given domain. Please include your efforts in obtaining your answer as well as (if possible) include the answer key.

Comment: Yes I got it. Thankyou. I think the problem is not correctly put.

Comment: Across the curve of the zero of the denominator, the function has an obvious first order pole. So no values can be supplied reasonably there. By the questions supplied, it's almost sure that it is a typo of $y^2 \to 2y $, . Such things happen under stress.  It's a standard example for examination of partial and absolute differentiabilty  Use polar coordinates for such problems.

Comment: From José Carlos Santos comment, you can see it is not defined on your domain, it may have typos

Answer (score 1):

Choose a path $y = (mx^3-x^2)/2$
Then
\begin{align}
 &\lim_{x\to 0} 2(x^3+y^3)/x²+2y\\
 &=\lim_{x\to 0} (2(x^3+((mx^2-x^2)/2)^3)/x^2+2y\\
&= 2/m
\end{align}

which is different for different values of $m$.

So the limit does not exist at $(0,0)$, it is not continuous.

Answer (score -1):

You found $f_1$ and $f_2$ at $(0,0)$, which is a start. You also need to find $f_{11},f_{12},f_{21},f_{22}$ at $(0,0)$ and compare them with $f_1,f_2,f_{11},f_{12},f_{21},f_{22}$ at points other than the origin by taking limits in all 6 cases as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

Comment: Question: why do we have to find the second derivatives?